# Having trouble with canvas, I've followed online tutorials but nothing shows in browser window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been learning how to use html5 recently and one aspect that really interests me is the canvas's ability to create animations. I have followed some online tutorials to some success but recently I found "thecodeplayer" where there are some awesome tutorials (if your in to it, check it out). I've got to the point where I've gone through it various times but still with no luck. The canvas does not show in my browser window when I load it up in chrome. Ive even turned off extensions like adblocker as suggested from some answers on this site. Its probably something obvious but I cant find where I seem to have gone wrong. Anyone who can point me in the right direction, thanks
Heres the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Canvas dimensions
var W = 500; var H = 500;

//create an array of particles
var particles = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
//This will add 50 particles to the array with random positions
particles.push(new create_particle());
}

//function to create multiple particles
function create_particle()
{
//Random position on the canvas
this.x = Math.random()*W;
this.y = Math.random()*H;

//add random velocity to each particle
this.vx = Math.random()*20-10;
this.vy = Math.random()*20-10;

//Random colors
var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
this.color = "rgba("+r+", "+g+", "+b+", 0.5)";

//Random size
this.radius = Math.random()*20+20;
}

var x = 100; var y = 100;

//animate the particle
function draw()
{

//paint canvas black, remove particle trails
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
//reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

//blend the particle with the BG
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

//draw particles from the array now
for(var t = 0; t < particles.length; t++)
{
    var p = particles[t];

    ctx.beginPath();

    //colors
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, 0, p.x, p.y, p.radius);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.4, p.color);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();

    //velocity
    p.x += p.vx;
    p.y += p.vy;

    //Stops balls moving out of canvas
    if(p.x < -50) p.x = W+50;
    if(p.y < -50) p.y = H+50;
    if(p.x > W+50) p.x = -50;
    if(p.y > H+50) p.y = -50;
}
}

setInterval(draw, 33);


</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"width="500"height="500"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the code in a function, and add a script tag below the `body` HTML, calling the canvas drawing function. The canvas element is not yet created when you want to use it for drawing on.

Result:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doCanvasStuff () {

    //Initializing the canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    ...

    setInterval(draw, 33);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

</body>

<script>
    doCanvasStuff();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I cant believe that it was something so simple that I'd missed.

Comment: No problem. Consider marking the answer (the big green tick mark) if it solved your problem.

Comment: It did, ive already been clicking it, "please wait 4 minutes". But it did answer, and again thanks

Comment: This is really old, but thumbing you up because this solved my issue, thanks man!